# Twisted + exceptions.AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, twisted

I have written a Twisted Server and a regular socket client(since the client does not have Twisted installed). A part of the server code is as follows

```
import time
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Server:
    def method(self, addr,port,sock):
        command = 'tcpdump -i any  \'src ' +str(addr) +' and port 80\' -w '+str(addr)+ '_download_' +str(time.time())+'.txt &'
        os.system(command)
        sock.transport.write('ok')


class Echo(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        s = Server()
        #extract client ip from the method self.transport.getPeer()
        #extract client port from the data received 
        print data
        s.method(client_ip, port, self)#the client ip and port are extracted from the request received

def main():
    f = Factory()
    f.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(33456, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This method works for the first client request but fails with the following error on second request

`exceptions.AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'time'` along with the line number of the command(I am using the time.time() method to get file name)

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on what I am doing wrong? or why it is throwing an error?

Edit:

I haven't posted the full code here but the traceback is

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 586, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 199, in doRead
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "dc.py", line 191, in dataReceived
    dc.multiQ(client_ip,multiq_port,self)
  File "dc.py", line 73, in multiQ
    command = 'tcpdump -i any  \'src ' +str(addr) +' and port 80\' -w '+str(addr)+ '_download_' +str(time.time())+'.txt &'#change any to eth0
exceptions.AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Comment: If the error is caused by `time.time()` then somewhere in your program your reassigned `time`. The code that you posted shouldn't work because `s` is not defined in `dataReceived()` (only `self.s` and `Echo.s` are available)

Comment: I am actually defining the object s inside dataReceived(), sorry about the confusion, I have edited my post above, I am not reassigning `time` anywhere else

Comment: post the full traceback

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian : I have updated the above post with the traceback

Comment: Check `time` variable again. Make sure there are no wildcard imports or `__builtins__` hacks.

Comment: This code as written does not cause the error you're citing.  You've modified it slightly, and this modification is what caused the problem.